# How to pass request.user in ajax call when using django?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send json data to django backend on my website.When I wanted to get user object in the view function,I got this "AnonymousUser" error.
Below is my code:

My api view:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def add_vote(request):
    if request.method =='POST':

        #I think this is where I can't figure out a way to deal with
        user = request.user

        serializer = VoteSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save(creator=user)
            return redirect(instance)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        votes = VoteTitle.objects.all()
        serializer = VoteSerializer(votes,many=True)
        print(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is my send function(a react class function):

```
sent_json() {
    let send_json = {
        title: this.state.title,
        subjects: [],
    };
    send_json.subjects = this.state.subjects.map((object) => ({
        name: object
    }));
    send_json = JSON.stringify(send_json);
    console.log(send_json);
    let csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    console.log(csrftoken);

    let header = {
        "method": 'POST',
        "body": send_json,
        "headers": {
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    };
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/voteapp/add/', header).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error);
    });
}
```

Error message shown in the django backend :

```
Internal Server Error: /voteapp/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 52, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/blog/voteapp/views.py", line 19, in add_vote
    instance = serializer.save(creator=user)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 215, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/blog/voteapp/serializers.py", line 17, in create
    vote = VoteTitle.objects.create(**data)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 397, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 537, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/Users/phil/Desktop/Web-Development/mini-blog/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 211, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x1045995f8>": "VoteTitle.creator" must be a "User" instance.
```

Error message alerted:

```
SyntaxError (DOM Exception 12): The string did not match the expected pattern.
```

Error message in the browser:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I was sure I have already logged in, so I must have missed something.

Comment: are you able to print csrf token with this line `console.log(csrftoken);` in your code. what happens when you do a get request

Comment: yeah csrftoken was successfully printed.I will add the response objects to the problem lately.

Comment: and what if you print the user in the view function under request.user?

Comment: @hansTheFranz I got "‎AnonymousUser" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your JavaScript, include the credentials when you use `fetch`:

```
let header = {
  "method":'POST',
  "body": send_json,
  "credentials": 'include',
  "headers":{
  "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
};
```

In the Django view, you should use `request.user` as you are already doing.

Comment: Yeah this worked.May I ask that why I still get this error message "SyntaxError (DOM Exception 12): The string did not match the expected pattern."  after post already succeeded

Comment: Sorry, my Python/Django is much better than my JavaScript, so I can't help with that.