# Django username is empty in a GET request

Tags: python, django, http, authentication

In my **views.py**, I have a function which uses GET method as shown below.

```
def status_codes(request):
try:
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    urls = linksextraction(url)
    url_codes.objects.filter().delete()
    print(request.user.username) # prints empty string
    # do something
    return JsonResponse(url_final_data)
except Exception:
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Invalid url"})
```

When i try to print the current logged in user, **it prints an empty string**. I have used the same in other functions which uses **POST and it works fine there.**

Can someone please help me getting the username in such scenarios where it involves GET method?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the user is authenticated ? According to [Anonymous User doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object), an empty username often shows that nobody is authenticated.

If your response is a `JsonResponse`, does it mean that you are using some kind of Ajax to call it ? In this case, credentials are not forwarded by default. For instance, this is how [it can be done with fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190949/how-to-pass-request-user-in-ajax-call-when-using-django)

Comment: request.user.is_authenticated false when GET method is used and True when POST method is used. Please help

Comment: How do you call this url ? Is this a link in the browser ? Or do you use javascript to call it ?

Comment: not using js, its an endpoint which is triggered in the browser. Yes, my admin pages are working

Comment: Can you show me your settings.py ? Settings of AUTH_USER, SESSION...

Comment: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

Answer (score 0):

Please check user is login.

```
print(request.user)
```

Comment: its printing "AnonymousUser"

Answer (score 0):

The reason i am not getting the username is because i forgot to keep the login decorator at top of my function