# Get request with django returns None for the user

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the details of the user who makes a get request in django. I'm using postman to perform the get request but when I try to print `request.user` and `type(request.user)`:

```
#In the view
class SomeView(APIView):
    ....
    ....
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        print(f'request: {request.user}, {type(request.user)')
```

I get `None` and `None` for the `user` and the `type`.

I've looked though many stackoverflow posts but I'm struggling finding out the reason.

From:

1. [Django username is empty in a GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60978348/django-username-is-empty-in-a-get-request)
2. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

I thought perhaps I'm not performing the get request with a user, but if that is the case, I should be getting an Anonymous object as the type for user right? But instead it's telling me it's `None`

I should mention from postman I'm under the `Authorization` tab, I've tried using a `Bearer Token` which I know I had the correct token as well as (separately) using basic auth by having the username and the password. Either method results in `request.user` being `None`.

If I just print out `request` I get:

```
<rest_framework.request.Request: GET '/test/number/33574677/'>,
```

I'm not sure what the issue here is, does it have something to do with the way I'm using postman to send the request? Or perhaps I'm missing something very trivial? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the authentication classes you are using. Can you share those? In this case it can happen if your authentication class returns `None` for the user

Comment: The problem was that the bearer token should have been in the header tab in postman, by doing that the user object was no longer None